# Trouble finding the position of an ellipse in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to find the ellipse in an image.
I first use filter over the image:

```
function [im_new]=getfilter(im)
imm1=imgaussfilt(im,10);
imm2=medfilt2(imm1,[5,5]);
imm3=imresize(imm2,0.25);
imm4=imresize(imm3,4);
im_new= imm4;
end
```

Then I try to find the ellipse but for some reason the algorithm is failing.

```
function[s,Thr]=findeclipse(im,itrun)
counts=hist(im(:),0:255);
Thr=otsuthresh(counts);
imm5=im2bw(im,Thr);
imm5=int16(im>1);
diskrange=1;
while 1 %iterating filtering util get the one circle
SE = strel('disk',diskrange,0);
BW2 = imerode(imm5,SE);
BW3 = imdilate(BW2,SE);
s = regionprops(BW3,{...
'Centroid',...
'MajorAxisLength',...
'MinorAxisLength',...
'Orientation'});
    if (length(s)>=1)&&(length(s)<2)
        break
    elseif length(s)==0
%         BW3=imm2;
        error('Could not find the pattern')
        break
    end
diskrange= diskrange+1; 
end
end
```

I need some assistance fixing the code for the attached image:
[image: image with eclipse]

I'm trying to find the eclipse so I will be able to find it's offset from the center.

Comment: Where is the eclipse? I only see lots of dots in the image, no eclipse.

Comment: this is the eclipse. the eclipse is the shape of all the dots above the black background

Comment: I’m not sure how that is an eclipse, but I’m not all too familiar with astronomy. Do you by any chance mean to say “ellipse”?

Comment: yes. ellipse. my typo...

Answer (score 0):

**1.- Is the eclipse same size as plotted stars**

I am not 100% sure if the eclipse to spot is a rather small dark ellipse among the stars show in the question image, or you really aim at plotting an ellipse encircling most of the stars in such image.

**2.- Perimeter Ellipse**

For the 2nd more probable :

```
im=imread('input_01.jpg');
im=im(:,:,1);

figure;
imshow(im);
hold on

counts=hist(im(:),0:255);
Thr=otsuthresh(counts);
imm5=im2bw(im,Thr);
imm5=int16(im>1);
diskrange=1;
while 1 %iterating filtering util get the one circle
SE = strel('disk',diskrange,0);
BW2 = imerode(imm5,SE);
BW3 = imdilate(BW2,SE);
s = regionprops(BW3,{...
'Centroid',...
'MajorAxisLength',...
'MinorAxisLength',...
'Orientation'});
    if (length(s)>=1)&&(length(s)<2)
        break
    elseif length(s)==0
%         BW3=imm2;
        error('Could not find the pattern')
        break
    end
diskrange= diskrange+1; 
end

plot_ellipse(s.MajorAxisLength/3,s.MinorAxisLength/3,s.Orientation,0,[size(im,1)/2 size(im,2)/2])
```

[image]

**3.- Pending**

Without any further data, it's now turn to fit the ellipse on the pool of stars, **IF** this is the case, that the eclipse to match is defined by the central group if stars.

Note that the origin [0 0] is the top left corner of the image.

Also, there's no need for the 3 layers RGB of the input image, just 1 layer is enough.

**4.- Support function** `plot_elipse`

this function is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWjMt.jpg) and the author is [M MA](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/14970)

```
function handle=plot_ellipse(major,minor,inc,phase,pos,options,type)
%PLOT_ELLIPSE   Draw ellipse using major, minor, inc and phase
%
%   Syntax:
%      HANDLE=PLOT_ELLIPSE(MAJOR,MINOR,INC,PHASE,POS,OPTYONS,TYPE)
%
%   Inputs:
%      MAJOR     Semi-major axis
%      MINOR     Semi-minor axis
%      INC       Inclination
%      PHASE     Phase
%      POS       Center of ellipse [ <x y> <x y z> {<0 0>} ]
%      OPTIONS   Plot line options [ 'b' ]
%      TYPE      Way phase is shown [ {1} 2 3 ]
%
%   Output:
%      HANDLES   handle for plotted line (also for a point if type is 3)
%
%   Comment:
%      If position has three elements (x, y and z), ellipse will be
%      plotted in the plane zz=z.
%
%   Example:
%      figure
%      plot_ellipse(2,1,45,20,[1 -1],'r'), axis equal
%
%   MMA 2-2003, martinho@fis.ua.pt
%   Department of physics
%   University of Aveiro
if nargin < 7
  type=1;
end
if nargin < 6
  options='b';
end
if nargin < 5
  pos=[0 0];
end
if major < minor
  warning('major axis cant be less than minor...')
end
% ellipse:
t=linspace(0,2*pi,100);
x=major*cos(t-phase*pi/180);
y=minor*sin(t-phase*pi/180);
[th,r]=cart2pol(x,y);
[x,y]=pol2cart(th+inc*pi/180,r);
% arrow:
if type == 1 | type == 2
  a=major/10;
end
if type == 3
  a=major/20; % length
end
Fi=30;      % angle.
teta=atan2(y(end)-y(end-1),x(end)-x(end-1))*180/pi;
fi=(180-Fi+teta)*pi/180;
fii=(180+Fi+teta)*pi/180;
if type == 3
  aux=3; % extra arrow point
  teta_aux=atan2(y(aux)-y(aux-1),x(aux)-x(aux-1))*180/pi;
  fi_aux=(180-Fi+teta_aux)*pi/180;
  fii_aux=(180+Fi+teta_aux)*pi/180;
  aux2=6; % extra arrow point
  teta_aux2=atan2(y(aux2)-y(aux2-1),x(aux2)-x(aux2-1))*180/pi;
  fi_aux2=(180-Fi+teta_aux2)*pi/180;
  fii_aux2=(180+Fi+teta_aux2)*pi/180;
end
Fi=Fi*pi/180;
P1=[x(1) y(1)];
P2=[P1(1)+a*cos(fi)/cos(Fi)  P1(2)+a*sin(fi)/cos(Fi)  P1(end)];
P3=[P1(1)+a*cos(fii)/cos(Fi) P1(2)+a*sin(fii)/cos(Fi) P1(end)];
if type == 3
  P1_aux=[x(aux) y(aux)];
  P2_aux=[P1_aux(1)+a*cos(fi_aux)/cos(Fi)  P1_aux(2)+a*sin(fi_aux)/cos(Fi)  P1(end)];
  P3_aux=[P1_aux(1)+a*cos(fii_aux)/cos(Fi) P1_aux(2)+a*sin(fii_aux)/cos(Fi) P1(end)];
  P1_aux2=[x(aux2) y(aux2)];
  P2_aux2=[P1_aux2(1)+a*cos(fi_aux2)/cos(Fi)  P1_aux2(2)+a*sin(fi_aux2)/cos(Fi)  P1(end)];
  P3_aux2=[P1_aux2(1)+a*cos(fii_aux2)/cos(Fi) P1_aux2(2)+a*sin(fii_aux2)/cos(Fi) P1(end)];
end
if type == 1
  x=pos(1)+[0 x NaN P2(1) P1(1) P3(1)];
  y=pos(2)+[0 y NaN P2(2) P1(2) P3(2)];
elseif type == 2
   x=pos(1)+[x NaN P2(1) P1(1) P3(1)];
   y=pos(2)+[y NaN P2(2) P1(2) P3(2)];
elseif type == 3
  x=pos(1)+x;
  y=pos(2)+y;
  x1=x(1);
  y1=y(1);
  x_aux=pos(1)+[P2_aux(1) P1_aux(1) P3_aux(1)];
  y_aux=pos(2)+[P2_aux(2) P1_aux(2) P3_aux(2)];
  x_aux2=pos(1)+[P2_aux2(1) P1_aux2(1) P3_aux2(1)];
  y_aux2=pos(2)+[P2_aux2(2) P1_aux2(2) P3_aux2(2)];
  x=[x NaN x_aux nan x_aux2];
  y=[y NaN y_aux nan y_aux2];
end
h=ishold;
if length(pos) == 2
  if type == 3
    handle.line=plot(x,y,options);
    hold on
    handle.poin1=plot(x1,y1,'k.')
  else
    handle=plot(x,y,options);
  end
elseif length(pos) == 3
  if type == 3
    handle.line=plot3(x,y,pos(3)*ones(size(x)),options)
    hold on
    handle.poin1=plot3(x1,y1,pos(3),'k.')
  else
    handle=plot3(x,y,pos(3)*ones(size(x)),options)
  end
else
  warning('wrong pos dimensions...')
end
if h~=1
   hold off
end


  [1]: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8604-plot_ellipse
```